# How to use pagefactory in POM? why we pass parameters in pagefactory?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, page-objects

While developing a script using Page Object Model, we use `PageFactory.initElements(driver,this)` to initialize the webelement.
How this is done and why we pass parameters 'driver' and 'this' ?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of the other, identical question. If the "driver and this" part makes this a substantially different question, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

> Page Factory Pattern is like an extension to Page Object Model , but Page Factory is much enhanced model. To start with, we just need to import package `org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory`

**Factory class can be used to make using Page Objects simpler and easier.**

We use Page Factory pattern to initialize web elements which are defined in Page Objects.

We should initialize page objects using `initElements()` method from PageFactory Class as below, Once we call initElements() method, all elements will get initialized. `PageFactory.initElements()` static method takes the driver instance of the given class and the class type, and returns a Page Object with its fields fully initialized.

```
public HompePage(WebDriver driver) 
{           
   this.driver = driver; 
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

> **Now question arise why we use Constructor?**

Solution=>
We should preferably use a constructor which takes a WebDriver instance as its only argument or falling back on a no-arg constructor. An exception will be thrown if the class cannot be instantiated.
Page Factory will initialize every WebElement variable with a reference to a corresponding element on the actual web page based on “locators” defined.

> Check below code by **using Simple POM**

```
public class BasePage 
{
private By username = By.id("username");
private By password = By.id("password");
private By loginBtn = By.name("loginbtn");

   public void userLogin(String userName, String password) 
   {
        driver.findElement(username).sendKeys("testuser");
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys("testpassword");
        driver.findElement(loginBtn).click();
   }
}
```

> **By using using Page Factory:**

```
public class BasePage {
  @FindBy(id= "username") private WebElement userName;
  @FindBy(id= "password") private WebElement password;
  @FindBy(id= "login") private WebElement loginBtn;

  public void userLogin(String userName, String password) {
    userName.sendKeys(userName);
    password.sendKeys(password);
    loginBtn.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add that this can also be solved by doing it in a main base object and have all pages using POM inherit that class.

Comment: How Can you please share the code?